# Angular 2 HTTP - Failed to fetch data with url parameters

Tags: angular

I'm unable to understand why this piece of code not set the value of this.video .
Here is troublesome component, I've comment where the error is (video-detail.component.ts):

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import { Component, OnInit }      from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Location }               from '@angular/common';
import { VideoService } from './video.service';
import { Video } from './video';

@Component({
    selector: 'video-detail',
    providers: [ VideoService ],
    templateUrl: './video-detail.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./video-detail.component.css']
})
export class VideoDetailComponent implements OnInit {

    video: Video;

    constructor(private videoService: VideoService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private location: Location) { }

    ngOnInit():void {
        this.route.params
            .switchMap((params:Params) => this.videoService.getVideoByID(params['id']))
            .subscribe(video => {
                console.log('video by id', video); // video exist, I've check it
                this.video = video  // this.video doesn't change, it remain undefined
            });             
    }
}
```

And here is my service. I don't think there are any error in this service. (video.service.ts) :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import { Video } from './video';

@Injectable()
export class VideoService {
    private headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    private listVideosURL = 'api/videos';

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getVideoByID(id): Promise<Video> {
        return this.getVideosList().then(videos => videos.find(video => video.id.videoId == id));
    }

    getVideosList(): Promise<Video[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.listVideosURL).toPromise()
            .then(response => {
                console.log('responseJson', response.json().data);
                this.listVid = response.json().data as Video[];
                return response.json().data as Video[];
            })
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        console.error('Error Bro!!!', error);
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

This is little insight for my InMemoryData :

```
import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';

export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {
    createDb() {
        let videos = [
            {
                "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
                "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/QkoKhBZWzraVqpegM1PMjSXcsNk\"",
                "id": {
                    "kind": "youtube#video",
                    "videoId": "10V6xet5ODk"
                },
                "snippet": {
                    "publishedAt": "2017-02-03T14:38:23.000Z",
                    "channelId": "UCNqFDjYTexJDET3rPDrmJKg",
                    "title": "Electro Swing Radio 2017 |  24/7 Music Live Stream | Gaming Music",
                    "description": "Electro Swing Radio 2017 | 24/7 Music Live Stream | Gaming Music.",
                    "thumbnails": {
                        "default": {
                            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/10V6xet5ODk/default_live.jpg",
                            "width": 120,
                            "height": 90
                        },
                        "medium": {
                            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/10V6xet5ODk/mqdefault_live.jpg",
                            "width": 320,
                            "height": 180
                        },
                        "high": {
                            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/10V6xet5ODk/hqdefault_live.jpg",
                            "width": 480,
                            "height": 360
                        }
                    },
                    "channelTitle": "7clouds",
                    "liveBroadcastContent": "live"
                }
            }, 
            { ... some other data }
        ];
        return {videos};
    }
}
```

Everything other works fine, service work, I've use the same service to show list of all data. I use InMemoryDataService and there is no problem.
And off course I've set all things needed in app.module.ts.
The problem is, why subscribe(video => {this.video = video}); failed to set the video property?

Comment: switchMap should return observable,

Comment: Where do you establish that the video is not set? If you console.log, the value is there?